# Plotting quaternion in Matlab using "engine.h" from c++

Tags: matlab, quaternions, matlab-figure, matlab-engine

I have an algorithm in C++ that uses Kalman Filter. Somewhere in the code a predict a Quaternion **q'** and then I update the Quaternion with Kalman Filter **q**.

I want to plot two graphics in Matlab with the evolution of the predicted quaternion and the corrected(updated) quaternion so I am using "engine.h" library to send quaternion info to Matlab during processing (actually what I send is a 4x1 matrix).

**So my question is**: What is the best way to plot a quaternion in Matlab so I can visually extract information? Is it maybe better to plot the angles separately?

Comment: Your question title does not match your actual question.

Comment: IF I am not mistaken, your question has nothing to do with "engine.h" or c++, right?

Comment: Well, it has because I will send the commands from c++ code ad this can give some problems, so later it is probable that I edit the question showing the full code. But it is true that the question can be thought in terms of matlab too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think a good option is sending the *quaternion* as a vector to MATLAB, using C++ MATLAB engine

> [qx qy qz qw]

Then, in MATLAB environment you can use a [toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20696-function-to-convert-between-dcm-euler-angles-quaternions-and-euler-vectors) for translating to Euler Angles, which is a common visual option.

For adding a path of a toolbox in matlab engine:

```
addpath(genpath('C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2010a\toolbox\SpinCalc'));
```

With spincalc toolbox, converting would be something like this:

```
Angles=SpinCalc('QtoEA321',Quaternion,0,0);
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, assuming that the question is "How to visualize in a nice way a 4D space",
I can think of a few options:

- Show multiple slices of the space, that is for (x,y,z,t) -> (x,y), (y,z),etc..
- Show (x,y) as scatter plot and encode the information of z in color, t in size of dot. For that you can use the **scatter** command :

> SCATTER(X,Y,S,C) displays colored circles at the locations specified
>      by the vectors X and Y (which must be the same size).

If your question was "How to visualize in a nice way quarternions,
 [check this out](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4801/how-can-you-visualize-a-quaternion)